# Merging two sorted Linked List in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, merge, linked-list, mergesort

Below is the Java Code solution to Merging two sorted Linked List, giving only the Heads of the two Sorted Linked List; list1 and list2.

My question is this; 1. even though the  solution is correct and passes all the Tests on the websites's Ide (Neetcode.com) successfully. I am confused about how the 'root.next' isn't null, how is the `root.next` value somehow the head of the merged lists. I have seen alot of videos online explaining it, but I still don't get it, somehow everyone expects that i should know that at the end of the code `root.next` is the head but clearly `root.next` was never assigned any value. Is there something i am missing?

2. In SolutionTwo how does 'prev.next' also return the head of the merged Linked List?

Please anyone with a very concise clear explanation?

```java
class Solution {

    public ListNode mergeTwoLists(ListNode list1, ListNode list2) {
        final ListNode root = new ListNode();
        ListNode prev = root;
        while (list1 != null && list2 != null) {
            if (list1.val < list2.val) {
                prev.next = list1;
                list1 = list1.next;
            } else {
                prev.next = list2;
                list2 = list2.next;
            }
            prev = prev.next;
        }
        prev.next = list1 != null ? list1 : list2;
        return root.next;
    }
}
```

```java
class SolutionTwo {
    public ListNode mergeTwoLists(ListNode list1, ListNode list2) {
        ListNode root = new ListNode();
        ListNode prev = root;

        while (list1 != null && list2 != null) {
            if (list1.val < list2.val) {
                root.next = list1;
                list1 = list1.next;
            } else {
                root.next = list2;
                list2 = list2.next;
            }
            root = root.next;
        }

        root.next = list1 != null ? list1 : list2;
       

        return prev.next;  // Return the head of the merged list
    }
}
```

I watched videos on youTube, neetcode.io and algoexperts.io

Comment: The key is understanding what `ListNode prev = root` actually does.  It assigns `prev` (a reference variable) to the contents of the reference variable `root`.  Therefore, the first manipulation of `prev` (as in `prev.next = ...`) is also manipulating what `root` references.  Then the `prev` reference variable is advanced to the next reference (`prev = prev.next`) and `root` remains the same, original reference.  Thus `root` retains its original reference.  Notice also `root` reference variable can never be reassigned because it is `final`.

Comment: @Computable oh wow thanks so much, this paints a clearer and more vivid picture. I'll try to solve this again to be sure I understand it well now. Thank you.

Comment: @Computable can you please explain why in SolutionTwo 'prev.next' returns the head of the newly merged Linked List as well ?

Comment: Its actually an identical solution - just the names of the variables are switched and the initial assignment (which is equivalent) is done on the "working" variable not the final variable.   Note that `prev` in the 2nd solution could have been `final`.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76559710/5459839) is a visualisation that may help (note that the variable names are different, but the algorithm is the same).

Answer (score 0):

`root` is a dummy node used with `prev` to simplify the code. The merged list will start with `root.next`. If both lists are empty, then `root.next` will be set to null on the next to last line of code. `root` will be automatically freed when the merge function returns.

Answer (score 0):

The two solutions are doing the same logic, but the only difference is that the variable that is moving over the `LinkedList`

The logic of the `while` is to check if any pointers, either `list1` or `list2`, are not null, then will compare the value of the current node and put the smallest value into the new `Linkedlist` then move the pointer to point the newly added node.

After `while` the code check where the pointer is not null to add the remaining node value.

Note: this code assumes that  two  LinkedList have  the same size

Here is the flow of the `First Solution`

[image]

---

, and here is the flow of the `Second Solution

[image]